# What is the typical accuracy of alignment rack?

Tags: alignment

I've looked at spec sheets from a few manufacturers - Hunter, Atlas, Hofman - and none list their accuracy or tolerance. 
My Subaru spec sheet shows ± 45' for camber, ±10' for toe angle, ± 30' for thrust angle, ± 1.5° for steering angle.

The tech at Pepboys told me their machine has a tolerance of approximately 15' and I just want to find out if that is typical.

Comment: A bigger effect on tolerance will be due to operator experience...

Comment: Sure, but I want to know what the machine is capable of, assuming a proficient operator

Comment: I think the question was just about the mechanical limits of the machine, and wondering if his local Pepboys has a typical/better/worse machine.