# How accurate is a "good" toe-in alignment?

Tags: alignment

I'm curious what is considered "Good", "Bad", and "Ugly" for alignments. I've seen specs such as [± 0.1° for toe in](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/67906/what-is-the-typical-accuracy-of-alignment-rack), but it's not clear to me if that's a CYA number; a "you probably won't accidentally drive off a cliff" number; or something in between.

Painting with a broad brush, what is the best accuracy we can reasonably do (like on a race car) and what is the worst which is still safe for a commuter car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Usually, when a car gets an alignment, the main reason for it is to help prevent wear to the tires. Unless the alignment is really out (like a toe-out situation), the alignment itself shouldn't precipitate an issue with safety. I state "toe-out" as a problem because this could create issues with tracking. If an alignment is off by several degrees (and quite possibly more) in any of the main measurements (camber/caster/toe-in), it shouldn't affect safety, but might affect drivability and will definitely affect tire wear.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks for the input! FWIW, the reason I started thinking about it is because I'm fixing landing gear in an airplane. :) It's a solid weld with no mechanism for shimming. I personally have no worries for the accuracy of the welder's fix, but it got be wondering just how accurate these kind of things have to be.

Comment: I get you ... a plane is quite a different beast from a car, though. Alignment might be a little bit more crucial for where you're talking about.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 for sure! Although, my hunch is that it's the other way around: the plane gets most of its high-speed steering authority from the rudder, and because it's only got three wheels it's very easy for the nosewheel to point in whatever direction nicely divides the toe-in by half. So for the purposes of my question I'm interested in cars because they drive much faster, over much greater distances, with 4 wheels instead of three. That, to me, seems like the more sensitive configuration.

Comment: Or, put another way, if the toe-in were critical on a plane we'd have some way of adjusting it. Instead, they're frequently just axles welded to dumb pieces of spring steel, https://backcountrypilot.org/images/originalphotos/3835/3232/dfcdd498334faf27e48baa75.jpg.

Comment: This is likely to be very opinion-based, and dependent on the type of car, the type of driving, the loading, the suspension, the dampers etc. Please watch this guy's videos - he covers toe-in/out in great depth: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYp2vvUgEqE